# Use TPM with Raspberry Pi to boot LUKS encrypted partition in unattended mode

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, tpm

I need to boot Raspberry Pi with LUKS encrypted root partition in unattended mode.
As I understand for this task I can use TPM (Trusted Platform Module) chip (that I can integrate with RaspberryPi using extension board) and tpm-luks.
I'd like to know if it's really possible to use TPM module in RaspberryPi to automatically validate boot partition integrity and get the key to decrypt root partition using TPM chip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a hardware integration problem here, you haven't reached the programming stage.

Comment: As I understand it it's not about hardware integration but System Architecture. Might still be off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The TPM is a passive device, it cannot "validate boot partition integrity". To ensure integrity of any kind you need a root of trust for measurement, which is never the TPM. You would need a trusted and locked down firmware that functions as such a RTM. You don't have that in the Pi's proprietary firmware.

Comment: @EricS.Bullington That's not true. It **IS** RoT Reporting and Storage, but it **IS NOT** the RoT for Measurement. The RTM has to be somewhere else. The TPM cannot guarantee that every executed bit of software is measured. It is, however, the TPM's responsibility to vouch for the integrety of the chain of trust by means of platform configuration registers.

Comment: Dear @EricS.Bullington, again:
The TPM **IS** the Root of Trust for Storage (=RTS). The TPM **IS** the Root of Trust for Reporting (=RTR). So of course it is a Root of Trust. That's what I already said. But it **IS NOT** and **CANNOT BE** the Root of Trust for Measurement (=RTM). There is a reason why these 3 concepts are treated seperately. And the paper you just linked says the same: "The  Core  Root  of  Trust  for  Measurement (CRTM)  MUST  be  an immutable portion  of  the  Host Platform’s initialization code that executes upon a Host Platform  Reset." It's not the TPM, it's the firmware.